# Local variable is not returning correct value + Async Actions Error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using Redux-react.

here is the small code of action :

```
export function copyYearData(year) {
    var listData = [
        {
            "categories": "Years"
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "label": 2013,
                    "value": 2013,
                },
                {
                    "label": 2014,
                    "value": 2014,
                },
                {
                    "label": 2015,
                    "value": 2015
                },
                {
                    "label": 2016,
                    "value": 2016
                },
                {
                    "label": 2017,
                    "value": 2017,
                },
                {
                    "label": 2018,
                    "value": 2018,
                },
                {
                    "label": 2019,
                    "value": 2019
                },
                {
                    "label": 2020,
                    "value": 2020
                },
                {
                    "label": 2021,
                    "value": 2021
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    var copyFrom = '';
    var copyTo = '';
    listData.map(function (obj) {
        if (obj.options) {
            obj.options.map(function (item) {
                if (item.value == year && year < new Date().getFullYear()) {
                    copyFrom = year;
                } 
                if (item.value == year && year >= new Date().getFullYear()) {
                    copyTo = year;
                }
            })
        }
    });
    if (copyFrom != '' && copyTo != '') {
        return {
            type: 'COPY_DATA',
            payload1: copyFrom,
            payload2: copyTo
        }
    }
};
```

Please, consider `year = 2015` (applicable for less than current year i.e. 2017) and `year = 2019` (applicable for greater than current year i.e. 2017)

my reducer name is 'helloReducer'.

when I use `console.log(store.getState().helloReducer);`

It's current output is `Object {copyFrom: "", copyTo: ""}`
Expected output will be `Object {copyFrom: 2015, copyTo: 2019}`

Also I got an error of `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Comment: hard to tell what you're trying to do here. 1) your function doesn't return anything. 2) map returns an array, so your array would be `[undefined, Object, undefined]` . is that what you want?

Comment: @azium: 1)yes, function not return anything. 2)it should not returning an array but value of data variable which is '2'.This needs to be return and this should be expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to traverse the array, don't want to `return` something for each element, so don't use `map`, use `forEach` it will not `return` anything by `default`, the Use this `code`:

```
export function copyYearData() {
    let data='';
    ['1','2','3'].forEach((item)=>{
        if(item === '2'){
            data = item;                
        }
    })
    if(data != ''){
        return{
             type: 'COPY_DATA',
             payload: data,
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. That works. But, I changed the code as per my needs. Can u please once go through it. I tried by using forEach() but, still code not work??

Comment: put the `console.log(copyFrom, copyTo)`, and check that is the value of these variables. before returning from function.